# Error: Response not successful: Received status code 405

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server, next.js14

I am having trouble getting around the graphql in apollo client\server for a Next.js (app router) project. terminal says `No HTTP methods exported in '..\app\api\graphql\route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.` I am new to these tech stacks . Also would like to know if the directories are correct. I have all 4 following files under the same folder `app/api/graphql`

Following are the codes

###### ApolloClient.ts

```
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
import { registerApolloClient } from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/rsc";

export const { getClient } = registerApolloClient(() => {
    return new ApolloClient({
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        link: new HttpLink({
            uri: "http://localhost:3000/api/graphql",

        }),
    });
});
```

###### typeDefs.ts

```
import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import { gql } from "graphql-tag";
        
const typeDefs = gql`
    type Query {
        hello: String
    }
`;

export default typeDefs;
```

###### resolver.ts

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        hello: () => 'world',
    },
};

export default resolvers;
```

###### graphql.ts

```
import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import typeDefs from './typeDefs';
import resolvers from './resolvers';
import { startServerAndCreateNextHandler } from "@as-integrations/next";

const graphql = new ApolloServer({
    resolvers,
    typeDefs
});

export default startServerAndCreateNextHandler(graphql);
```

Here is the error it says on the browser

```
    Unhandled Runtime Error
    Error: Response not successful: Received status code 405
    
    Call Stack
    new ApolloError
    (rsc)\node_modules\@apollo\client\errors\index.js (39:0)
    eval
    (rsc)\node_modules\@apollo\client\core\QueryManager.js (777:37)
    both
    (rsc)\node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\observables\asyncMap.js (22:0)
    eval
    (rsc)\node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\observables\asyncMap.js (11:56)
    new Promise
    <anonymous>
    Object.then
    (rsc)\node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\observables\asyncMap.js (11:0)
    Object.eval [as error]
    (rsc)\node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\observables\asyncMap.js (24:0)
    notifySubscription
    (rsc)\node_modules\zen-observable-ts\module.js (137:0)
    onNotify
    (rsc)\node_modules\zen-observable-ts\module.js (176:0)
    SubscriptionObserver.error
    (rsc)\node_modules\zen-observable-ts\module.js (229:0)
    eval
    (rsc)\node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\observables\iteration.js (7:49)
    Array.forEach
    <anonymous>
    iterateObserversSafely
    (rsc)\node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\observables\iteration.js (7:0)
    Object.error
    (rsc)\node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\observables\Concast.js (76:42)
    notifySubscription
    (rsc)\node_modules\zen-observable-ts\module.js (137:0)
    onNotify
    (rsc)\node_modules\zen-observable-ts\module.js (176:0)
    SubscriptionObserver.error
    (rsc)\node_modules\zen-observable-ts\module.js (229:0)
    handleError
    (rsc)\node_modules\@apollo\client\link\http\parseAndCheckHttpResponse.js (170:0)
    eval
    (rsc)\node_modules\@apollo\client\link\http\createHttpLink.js (145:27)
    process.processTicksAndRejections
    node:internal/process/task_queues (95:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

in the App Router you need to export functions as HTTP method names like so:

```
export const GET = (req: Request) => {
    return Response.json({ posts: [] })
}

export const POST = (req: Request) => {
    return Response.json({ posted: true })
}

export const DELETE = (req: Request) => {
    return Response.json({ deleted: true })
}

export const PUT = (req: Request) => {
    return Response.json({ updated: true })
}
```

Now as I checked, `@as-integrations/next` has not created any special functions for that which is reasonable as they wanted to keep it supported for the pages router as well. Instead, they recommend [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@as-integrations/next#app-router-route-handlers) it to use it this way:

###### graphql/route.ts

```js
const handler = startServerAndCreateNextHandler(server);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Comment: Can you please let me know, which file to add the export functions?

Comment: @user17449555 the first code block was just an example of how the API routes in the nextjs should be implemented. the 2nd code block is just what you should add (the last line)

Comment: still getting the same error.

Comment: @user17449555 is the file this? `app/api/graphql/route.ts`

Comment: ah, I renamed the file to a different one. Is there anything I need to change in the setting or the filename has to be route.ts?

Comment: @user17449555 no everything is fine. unless you still have an issue with it

Answer (score 1):

It was solved having page.ts with the following

```
const userQuery = gql`
  query {   
      hello    
  }
`;
```